# Properties of $v_p(a-b) =n, p$ adic order when $\gcd(a,p)=\gcd(b,p)=1$ about $a^p-b^p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$v_p(a-b) =n, p \not = 2$ adic order when $\gcd(a,p)=\gcd(b,p)=1$
I need to show for every $n \in \Bbb N$ 
that:
 $$v_p(a^p-b^p)=n+1$$

I know how to proof the case for $p=2$ when $n \ge 2 $
but for this one i can`t find way to show $x^p-y^p$ such for $p=2$: $a^2 -b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given that $a=b+up^n$ with $u$ not a multiple of $p$.
Then $$ a^p-b^p=\sum_{k=1}^p{p\choose k}b^{p-k}u^kp^{nk}$$
Using the fact that $p\mid {p\choose k}$ for $0<k<p$, we see:
The summand for $k=1$ is divisible precisely by $p^{n+1}$, the summand for $k=p$ is divisible by $p^{np}>p^{n+1}$, and all in-between summands are divisible at least by $p^{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $p\mid a-b$ we have $a\equiv _p b$, so

$$a^p-b^p = \underbrace{(a-b)}_{m\cdot p^n}(\underbrace{a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+...+b^{p-1}}_{\equiv p\cdot a^{p-1}}) = m\cdot p^n\cdot p  \cdot k$$

where $a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+...+b^{p-1} =p\cdot k$ and obviously $p\not{|}\; mk$

Comment: How do you know that $a^{p-1}+...+b^{p-1}\equiv p \cdot a^{p-1}$?

Comment: @AaronJohnson Read first line

Comment: And why is it obvious that $p \nmid k$?

Comment: Because $\gcd(a,p)=1$

Comment: But you only know that $a^{p-1}+... + b^{p-1}$ is not congruent to $p \cdot a^{p-1}$, they're not equal... so it seems possible to get factors of $p$ in $k$.